# What are the actual API limits?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

On the Stackdriver Trace documentation (https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/quotas) I see there are `Quota unit cost per API call`, but that doesn't really tell me what the true API limits are.

For something like `BatchWriteSpans` the unit cost is 1, but it doesn't tell me how many or how large can my Spans be.

I would like to get more insight into the limits of the API and if there is anyway I can pull this information so that I don't have to hardcode these limits in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The "unit cost" is just telling you how many of request-per-second quota units are used each request. As BatchWriteSpans has cost 1, you can make 4800 BatchWriteSpans each minute.

Below that are the limit on what can be in a request. For example, each span can only have 32 labels, each of which can be at most 128 bytes key and 256 bytes value.

There is no documented limit on the number of spans in BatchWriteSpans, but I'd assume it is the same as PatchTraces, ie 25000.